# for each JavaScript Support in IE?

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
<script>
function toggle(source) {

  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('DG1');
  for each(var checkbox in checkboxes)
    checkbox.checked = source.checked;

  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('DG2');
  for each(var checkbox in checkboxes)
    checkbox.checked = source.checked;

  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('DG3');
  for each(var checkbox in checkboxes)
    checkbox.checked = source.checked;

  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('DG4');
  for each(var checkbox in checkboxes)
    checkbox.checked = source.checked;

  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('DG5');
  for each(var checkbox in checkboxes)
    checkbox.checked = source.checked;
}
</script>

<input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" />Select All<br/>

<form method=POST action="DGUsageServlet">
    <input type="checkbox" name="DG1">DG1</input>
    <input type="checkbox" name="DG2">DG2</input>
    <input type="checkbox" name="DG3">DG3</input>
    <input type="checkbox" name="DG4">DG4</input>
    <input type="checkbox" name="DG5">DG5</input>
</form>
```

How can I make the above script to work in IE?

Comment: Indenting code 4 spaces will give you code formatting.

Answer (score 47):

Note that Firefox no longer supports for each loops, so this applies to *every* browser, not just Internet Explorer. [See this MDN article for alternatives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/For-each-in_loops_are_deprecated).

---

Internet Explorer doesn't support "for each" loops (along with other modern browsers, which have dropped support for them). You will need to change the code to use regular for loops:

```
function toggle(source) {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('DG1');
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
    }
    ...
}
```

Or, you could use a library like jQuery and do it like this:

```
function toggle(source) {
    $("input[name^=DG]").attr("checked", source.checked);
}
```

Comment: Yes. A pox on the head of multiple javascript implementations.

Comment: Back in the day you only had to be *source* compatible across multiple architectures.  Now you have to be "binary" compatible across several browser architectures, plus a pile of loosely scattered bricks with a dead badger trapped underneath, screaming for mercy.

Comment: -1 `[1,2,3].length` may be 4 because of toString in IE8. Better you use hasOwnProperty.

Comment: @PeterRader I'm not sure what you're referring to.

Comment: Im referring to the usage of `length` in your suggestion.

Comment: @PeterRader I don't know of any case where `checkboxes.length` would be incorrect.

Comment: "for each iterates over all the properties of the object including properties from its prototype". This is not correct. Array.prototype.forEach() does *not* iterate over anything other than elements in the array. Also very useful for sparse arrays. Using forEach() on the following array will only give you the two iterations, skipping over the undefined indexes between them. Looping through the length would iterate 21 times, requiring one to manually skip the undefined elements: `var arr = []; arr[10] = 'hello'; arr[20] = 'world';`

Comment: @Nate The question and answer are referring to the proprietary/deprecated "for each" loop supported by Firefox, not the forEach function, which is appropriate/useful for iterating over arrays.

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions That's showing results for the `Array.forEach` function, which is different (but can be made to work by using `Array.prototype.forEach.call(checkboxes, callback)`. The modern version is the `for...of` loop introduced in ES2015, but won't work if you need to support IE11.

Answer (score 14):

Or you might try and extend the Array object for browsers that don't support the foreach method on it as suggested here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference:Objects:Array:forEach#Compatibility

Answer (score 8):

i think **jQuery.each** is the best solution for it

```
var idArr = ["LocationFirst","LocationSecond","LocationThird","LocationFourth","LocationFifth"];

 $.each(idArr,function(index, entry) {
   //some code
 });
```

it will iterate over all the elements in the array "idArr" and can do some thing with each element.

Answer (score 4):

Natively IE8 is out of date to **foreach**, but how do I use jQuery, I opted for **jQuery.each** to overcome this problem.

My copy and paste from jQuery API Doc:

```
var obj = {
   "flammable", "inflammable"
   "duh": "no duh"
};
$. each (obj, function (key, value) {
   alert (key + ":" + value);
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use a modified form of for each in Internet Explorer, the syntax is as follows.

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('DG2');
for (var i in checkboxes)
  checkboxes[i].checked = 'true';
```

Comment: `i` may be `toString` in ie8 too.

Answer (score 3):

I had a problem with forEach on IE 11

And i have found a workaround solution like that

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByName('element_name')).forEach(function (el) {
    if (el.checked) {
       console.log('checked');
    }
```

It is working for me fine.

Comment: that's the best solution, imho. short form: `[].slice.call( ... ).forEach( ... )`

Answer (score 2):

To complete Matthew Crumley's answer, you may also have a problem with the `getElementByName()` failure in IE, explained [here](http://jszen.blogspot.com/2004/07/whats-in-name.html):

> The little-used `getElementsByName()` method is part of the DOM Level 1 specification and is supported by both Internet Explorer and Mozilla/Firefox. getElementsByName()
>
> According to the HTML 4.01 spec, the only elements that support NAME attributes are `BUTTON, TEXTAREA, APPLET, SELECT, FORM, FRAME, IFRAME, IMG, A, INPUT, OBJECT, MAP, PARAM and META`. So to place a `NAME` inside a `DIV` is actually invalid HTML.

(So it will work in your case (`NAME` of an `INPUT` field), but it is unsafe to use it in IE)

> Moz/Firefox doesn't have a problem with this and will happily return all three DIV elements. But MSIE treats it the invalid `NAME` attribute as an [expando attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/author/dhtml/reference/properties/expando.asp) and excludes those elements

A possible fix is given with [this script](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet293.htm).

---

Note: when you are coding a `for`, alwatys add then enclosing curling brackets `{ and }`: it is safer. If you add a second line of code in your loop, it will be taken into account by the `for` block.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
[].slice.call(...).forEach(...);
```

example:

```
[].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('h1') ).forEach(function(h1) { 
    console.log(h1);
});
```

Or better add one times:

```
// make IE9+ support forEach:
if (window.NodeList && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) 
    NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
```

and then always use compact syntax:

```
document.querySelectorAll('h1').forEach(function(h1) { 
    console.log(h1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would clean it up a bit.

```
function select(){
    var butt = document.getElementById('selectall');
    butt.onclick = selectall;

    function selectall(){
        for(var i=1;i<6;i++){
            var id='DG'+i;
            var all = document.getElementById(id);
            all.setAttribute('checked','checked');
        }
    }   
}
```

But It works only for getElementById() (and not getElementsByName(), what I dont understand ). Just add to every input id='selectall', id='DG1'...