# Why does for each not work in Internet Explorer and what is the alternative?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, loops

This function is working fine in Firefox, but doesn't work on IE

What could be the problem?

```
function toggle(source) {
   checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('pay[]');

   for each(var checkbox in checkboxes)
     checkbox.checked = source.checked;
   checkTotal();    
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [for each JavaScript Support in IE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412447/for-each-javascript-support-in-ie)

Answer (score 4):

I guess **for each** isn't supported by IE yet.

Use this instead:

```
for(var i=0;i<checkboxes.length;++i)
{
  checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
}
```

It works regardless of the browser/version

Answer (score 2):

`for each` is a [non-standard Mozilla extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in).

Treat it as a normal array.

```
var i, checkbox;
for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkbox = checkboxes[i];
}
```

Comment: Also, `document.getElementsByName()` returns a `NodeList` rather than an array, which is a host object and therefore not guaranteed to be enumerable.

Comment: Actually, `for each` is in fact standardized.  It's part of the ECMA-357 standard.  It's just that Mozilla is the only browser that implements that standard.

Answer (score -2):

```
for (i in checkboxes )
     checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
```

Comment: You forgot to mention that you can only do that when you're 100% sure that there are no and will never be enumerable properties in the Array prototype.