# IE 8 does not support foreach method

Tags: extjs, internet-explorer-8, foreach

This code not working in Internet Explorer 8.

```
documenttab.query('.field,.button').forEach(function(c){c.setDisabled(false);});
```

I get the error **SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'**

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412447/for-each-javascript-support-in-ie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ext has a forEach method. Where supported, it will defer to the native method:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Array-method-forEach

```
Ext.Array.forEach(documenttab.query('.field,.button'), function(c){
    c.setDisabled(false);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Mozilla also publishes code for methods which you can put near the top of your JS and it will create them if they don't exist.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 4):

I believe this should solve your issue.

```
vals = documenttab.query('.field,.button')
for (i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
    vals[i].setDisabled(false);
}
```

Comment: I like this solution the best because it doesn't require any extra libraries and this is how people did it before forEach came around.