# Why I have this error: Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach' for Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I am Working on Javascript on a jenkins plugin using maven and I have this code:

```
   function arrayElements(element, index, array) 
     {
         var arrayPaths = element.split("\\");
         var projectSource = arrayPaths[2];
         var array = element.split("_");
         if (projectSource === global ) {             
             if (array[2]===filtro){
             document.getElementById("source").options.add(new Option(arrayPaths[3], element));
             }
         }
     }
    function fillCompiledSource(object, projects)
    {
        document.getElementById("source").innerHTML = "";        
        global = document.getElementById("branches").value;     
        projects.forEach(arrayElements)
    }
    var projects = new Array();</script><script>
    function fillCombo()
    {
         document.getElementById("source").innerHTML = "";
         global = document.getElementById("branches").value;     
         var array = document.getElementById("branches").value.split('/');
         global = array[1];
         projects.forEach(arrayElements)       
    }
```

This fail only in internet explorer and only when document Mode is IE8 standarts I don't know what is the reason and how I can resolve that..

Pd: The Internet explorer is 10

Comment: IE8 doesn't support `forEach`

Comment: asked and answered many times http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412447/for-each-javascript-support-in-ie

Comment: My problem is diferent because I can't use JQuery I am working on a Jenkins plugin using maven..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yeap, its because IE8 *does not* implement `Array.forEach` (neither many other more modern JS methods). If you need to work in IE8, you will have to [shim it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) (see the compatibility section).

By the way, MDN has resources for most of the other unsupported methods too.

Answer (score 4):

This might help.
To solve the problem in jQuery:

```
//This will fail in IE8
myObject.each(function(index, value){
 //your code goes here
});

//This will work in IE8 and all modern browsers
$.each(myObject, function(index, value){
 //your code goes here
});
```

Comment: @Daniel, Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can also bind the unexisting forEach function to Array.prototype.forEeach.

```
(function () {
    if ( typeof NodeList.prototype.forEach === "function" ) return false;
    NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
})();
```

I found it in this post [https://tips.tutorialhorizon.com/2017/01/06/object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-foreach](https://tips.tutorialhorizon.com/2017/01/06/object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-foreach/)/.